# Winui3 Desktop; ObservableCollection, updating UI when property changes? Updating from different thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, observablecollection, winui-3

This is a small test app to try and figure this problem out from my main app. I'll paste the code first.

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ThreadTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ThreadTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddPosition}" Content="Add To List" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.OutputString, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5"/>
            
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PositionCollection, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border BorderBrush="BlueViolet" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                <TextBlock Text="ID" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="BlueViolet" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                <TextBlock Text="Place" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:PositionModel">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=ID, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Path=Place, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
   
</Window>
```

ViewModel (MainViewModel.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ThreadTest {
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private String outputString = "Empty";

        public MainViewModel() {

        }

        public String OutputString {
            get { return outputString; }
            set { SetProperty(ref outputString, value); }
        }

        private Random _random = new Random();  
        private int _id = 0;
        
        private ObservableCollection<PositionModel> _positioncollection = new();
        public ObservableCollection<PositionModel> PositionCollection {
            get { return _positioncollection; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _positioncollection, value); }
        }

        public async void AddPosition() {
            Progress<PositionModel> progress = new();
            progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;

            // Increase id for each new position added.
            _id++;
            // Setup/
            var _position = new PositionModel {
                ID = _id,
                Place = _random.Next(1, 1000), // Get a random starting point.
            };

            PositionCollection.Add(_position);            
            PositionsClass positionsClass = new(ref _position, progress);

            await Task.Run(() => { positionsClass.Start(); });
        }

        private void Progress_ProgressChanged(object sender, PositionModel e) {
            // This is so I can see that the thread is actually running.
            OutputString = Convert.ToString(e.Place);
        }
    }
}
```

BindableBase.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ThreadTest {
    public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T originalValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            if (Equals(originalValue, newValue)) {
                return false;
            }

            originalValue = newValue;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

PositionModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ThreadTest {
    public class PositionModel {

        /*
        //Impliment INotifyPropertyChanged up above if using this.
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T originalValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            if (Equals(originalValue, newValue)) {
                return false;
            }

            originalValue = newValue;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            return true;
        }

        private int _id = 0;
        public int ID {
            get { return _id; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
        }

        private int _place = 0;
        public int Place {
            get { return _place; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _place, value); }
        }
        */

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Place { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

PositionsClass.cs:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadTest {
    public class PositionsClass {
        private IProgress<PositionModel> _progress;
        private PositionModel _position;

        public PositionsClass(ref PositionModel position, IProgress<PositionModel> progress) {
            _progress = progress;
            _position = position;
        }

        public void Start() {

            StartFakePosition();
        }

        private void StartFakePosition() {

            // Just using a quick loop to keep the numbers going up.
            while (true) {
                _position.Place++;

                // Send position back.
                _progress.Report(_position);

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically you'll click the 'add to list' button which will then create the PositionsClass positionsClass, create and populate the PositionModel _position, create an ObservableCollection PositionCollection (bound to listview on xaml) then spin off the class into it's own thread. The class will get _position and increase its .Place, then progress.report the _position back to main thread.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the PositionCollection (of ObservableCollection) to update the lisview ui. I subscribed to progress.ProgressChanged and update the OutputString just to make sure the class is actually running and incrementing which does work.

I've tried various things I've found on the web, including different inherited ObversableCollection methods, none of which work or I missunderstood them.

I thought implementing an INotifyPropertyChange on PositionModel.cs itself would work (the commented out code), but doing so brings up a cross thread error. I imagine it's because positionsClass on a seperate thread is updating .Place which is causing the cross thread error?

Can anyone help explain how to get the ObservableCollection to update the ui when it's property changes in my example above? Thanks! In my main app, I'll be updating a lot of properties on a separate thread, rather than just the 2 in this example. Which is why I thought it'd be easier to just send the whole model back in a progress.report.

Comment: As far as I can see your `PositionModel.Place` property is bound to the ItemTemplate of a xaml listview. At the same time it's incremented from the non-UI-thread of the Task started in `MainViewModel.AddPosition`. That's why you get cross-thread-issues.
To get rid of them you have to ensure the UI-bound properties are modified by the UI thread. Most of the time people use `Dispatcher.CheckAccess` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`, `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` to do so.

Comment: Yeah, so, what I use is `private IProgress<PositionModel> _progress; ` and `private PositionModel _position;` to report the _position (PositionModel) back to the calling thread from that task.run thread. And all that works fine, OutputString shows it updating in the UI. But ObservableCollection doesn't update the ui on the property changes. If I add the INotifyPropertyChanged directly to the PositionModel.cs, that's when it brings up cross thread error. I don't even know if that's the right route to go down.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. First I enable the INotifyProperty on PositionModel.cs code above (the commented out part). Then I add:

```
        private readonly DispatcherQueue _dispatcherQueue = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
        public CoreDispatcher Dispatcher { get; }
```

To the MainViewModel, and modify AddPosition to:

```
        public async void AddPositionDispatcher() {

            // Increase id for each new position added.
            _id++;
            // Setup/
            var _position = new PositionModel {
                ID = _id,
                Place = _random.Next(1, 1000), // Get a random starting point.
            };

            PositionCollection.Add(_position);
            PositionsClassDispatcher positionsClassDispatcher = new(_position, _dispatcherQueue);

            await Task.Run(() => { positionsClassDispatcher.Start(); });
        }
```

Where I send a DispatcherQueue to the new modified PositionsClassDispatcher.cs:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using System.Threading;


namespace ThreadTest {
    internal class PositionsClassDispatcher {
        private PositionModel _position;
        DispatcherQueue _queue;

        public PositionsClassDispatcher(PositionModel position, DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue) {
            _queue = dispatcherQueue;
            _position = position;
        }

        public void Start() {
            StartFakePosition();
        }

        private void StartFakePosition() {

            // Just using a quick loop to keep the numbers going up.
            while (true) {  
              _queue.TryEnqueue(() => {
                    _position.Place++;
                });
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will take the DispatcherQueue and use TryEnqueue to update _position.Place. ObvservableCollection now properly updates UI when properties are updated. Also update the XAML to use the new AddPositionDispatcher().

Also, having to use DispatcherQueue rather than Dispatcher as WinUI3 seems to not have have Dispatcher anymore.

[Window.Dispatcher Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.dispatcher?view=winui-3.0)

> Window.Dispatcher may be altered or unavailable in future releases. Use Window.DispatcherQueue instead.

Which has caused quite a few problems trying to figure this problem out, as a lot of info out there is based on Dispatcher rather than DispatcherQueue.

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into the problem.